# Remove rows with too many delimiters

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have a file with fields separated by the '`` ` ``' character. But sometimes the actual data also contains this character. How can I remove all the erroneous rows and retain only the good quality data.

Sample Row as below . Towards the end 'fff`ff' this is the erroneous column . in such case The row should be eliminated.

```````````
xxx`1000165811`2012`2012_q2`05/09/2012 22:02:00`1343`04/07/2004 00:00:00`05/09/2012 00:00:00````F`1`1.000000`9.620000`1.0000````fff`Not`Free`Free`1.000000`9.620000`0.000000`1.0000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`56565666`255.590000`21`0`0.000000```ddd`dddd`FA May 2012 ddd`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`05/30/2012 00:00:00`05/30/2012 00:00:00`1.000000`ddd`ddd`OW`DL`dd dd dd`ddd`dd`dd dd`dd dd`0.000000`0.000000``````````0.000000`````````Non_Mobile`9.620000`1.000000`1`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`9.620000`9.620000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`0.000000`28.590000`6.990000`**fff`ff**`````````9.620000`1.000000`1
```````````

Comment: Give some example data

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: re-source the file and use a delimiter that isn't in the data? (`|`)? Good luck.

Comment: Does it really take a line 1000 characters long to demonstrate your problem? Come up with a few lines of MUCH briefer sample input (say 6 lines of 30 chars per line and include lines that should and lines that should not be removed) and add the expected output. Also describe how to identify these "bad" tick characters separately from the "good" ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know what the correct number of delimiters in a line is.  You need to count the actual number of delimiters in each line, and reject those lines where the actual count is not the correct number.

Assuming the the correct number of separators is `n=5`, then you could try:

```
n=5
grep -E '^[^`]*(`[^`]*){'"$n"'}$' data
```

The regex uses extended regular expressions (`-E`).  The regex matches the start of the line, zero or more non-back-ticks, then a sequence of `n` occurrences of a back tick followed by zero or more non-back-ticks, followed by the end of line.  Because the back-tick is a shell metacharacter, it is best to enclose most of the regular expression in single quotes.  The variable `$n` could be used without the double quotes around it, but it's generally best to enclose variables in double quotes.  Clearly, you can also use this version too:

```
grep -E '^([^`]*`){'"$n"'}[^`]*$' data
```

Given a data file `data`:

```````
AA`BB`CC`DD`EE`FF
AABB`CC`DD`EE`FF
A`A`BB`CC`DD`EE`FF
`BB`CC`DD`EE`FF
`BB`CC`DD`EE`
``CC`DD`EE`
``CC``EE`
````EE`
`BB```EE`
`````
``````
````
Welcome`to`the`land`of`insanity
```````

The output of the command is:

``````
AA`BB`CC`DD`EE`FF
`BB`CC`DD`EE`FF
`BB`CC`DD`EE`
``CC`DD`EE`
``CC``EE`
````EE`
`BB```EE`
`````
Welcome`to`the`land`of`insanity
``````

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -v "[^`]`[^`]`[^`]`"
```

you need to have one more times that the correct lines would have

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of "Be careful what you ask for", here is a "one-liner" (spread over three lines for readability) that will do what was asked, using only `awk` and assuming that $FILE is the relevant filename.

```
awk -F'`' -v file="$FILE" '
  BEGIN{ while(getline<file){if (min==""||NF<min){min=NF}}}
  NF==min' "$FILE"
```

This incantation first determines the minimum number of delimiters per line (without sorting the file), and then rejects all lines with more than that many.

(This is similar to Ed Morton's proposal, but without the bug :-)

Comment: Good idea, but just do it in one call to awk, no need for all that other stuff: `awk -F'\`' 'NR==FNR{min=(NF<min?NF:min);next} NF==min' file file`. This approach will fail if the OP has a file where ALL lines have this "bad" delimiter though.